# Forbidden access on Apache in Mac Lion

Tags: osx-lion, apache-http-server

I'm trying to configure Apache to work with Symfony in my Macbook Pro. I Have installed Lion OSX.

1. I uncommented the line **Include `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`**  on `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.
2. I configured Apache by editing the `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`. and adding the following:

::

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *.80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/luiscberrocal/Documents/dev/lion_test/web"
  ServerName lion.localhost
<Directory "/Users/luiscberrocal/Documents/dev/lion_test/web">
   Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

3. Added the following to */private/etc/hosts*
    127.0.0.1   lion.localhost

Now when I access `http://localhost/test.php` I get the following message

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /test.php on this server.
```

Apache/2.2.20 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6 with Suhosin-Patch Server at localhost Port 80

I already tried:

```
chmod 777 test.php

chmod +x test.php
```

I get the same message if I try to access `http://lion.localhost/`

I opened the `/var/log/apache2/error_log` and this is what I found relevant:

```
[Sat Dec 31 09:37:49 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.20 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 31 09:37:53 2011] [error] [client ::1] (13)Permission denied: access to /test.php denied
[Sat Dec 31 09:37:55 2011] [error] [client ::1] (13)Permission denied: access to /test.php denied
[Sat Dec 31 09:38:13 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Dec 31 09:38:13 2011] [error] (EAI 8)nodename nor servname provided, or not known: Could not resolve host name *.80 -- ignoring! httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Luis-Berrocals-MacBook-Pro.local for ServerName
[Sat Dec 31 09:38:14 2011] [warn] mod_bonjour: Cannot stat template index file '/System/Library/User Template/English.lproj/Sites/index.html'.
[Sat Dec 31 09:38:14 2011] [warn] mod_bonjour: Cannot stat template index file '/System/Library/User Template/English.lproj/Sites/index.html'.
[Sat Dec 31 09:38:14 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Dec 31 09:38:14 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Dec 31 09:38:14 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.20 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 31 09:38:18 2011] [error] [client ::1] (13)Permission denied: access to /test.php denied
[Sat Dec 31 09:38:19 2011] [error] [client ::1] (13)Permission denied: access to /test.php denied
[Sat Dec 31 10:18:09 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /test.php denied
[Sat Dec 31 10:18:15 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you made sure all folders in the file path are `executable` (`+x`) for all users?

Comment: Checked the path and it is executable. I'm inclined to think that it is a problem with my content of the httpd-vhosts.conf because if I delete what I added I can access http://localhost/test.php.

Comment: Why did you define the same virtual host (for port 80) twice? Have you tried removing the default entry? I know, different name, but still..?

Answer (score 3):

Put

```
<Directory "your/custom/directory">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

at the end of /opt/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

take a look at line 180 to 225 to see what's going on.

Comment: This makes it work!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Apache config file is not written correctly.

I would take the directory stuff and move it above the VirtualHost, also you cannot access the second virtual host you created because your trying to access it with the wrong hostname. You would need to use http://lion.localhost instead of localhost.

I would also just remove the first virtual host setting and than change the lion.localhost to localhost for simplicity.

Hope that helps,

Nick

```
<Directory "/Users/luiscberrocal/Documents/dev/lion_test/web">
   Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Users/luiscberrocal/Documents/dev/lion_test/web"
   ServerName lion.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The error is a configuration / permissions issue. You'll have to debug it. Wish the correct answer would be promoted on SU.

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` just comment the lines

```
User _www
Group _www
```

and make the User as the user you are logged in. That should work.

Comment: This has the likely side effect of having a web server run with near-administrative, or administrative, privileges on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't work out it to work with port 80. What finally worked for me was using this on my */private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf*

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080

Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
        DocumentRoot "/Users/luiscberrocal/NetBeansProjects/mroute_rest_service/web"
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        <Directory "/Users/luiscberrocal/NetBeansProjects/mroute_rest_service/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then run `sudo chmod 777 cache` and `sudo chmod 777 logs/`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case the directory didn't have the proper permissions.

I changed them to 755 and solved the problem.